# Collections in Alphabetical order

Tags: outliner

Is there a way in the outliner, the collections I make to be in alphabetical order? for example, I have over 30 collections, the folder with the letter A, is after the letter F, and the letter S is on the top of the collections, all is mixed up.

Comment: One way that works for me is just click and drag them to where I want them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated full code for menu access and a few sorting options(7-Feb). Original answer at bottom.

Sorting functions added to context menus for 'OUTLINER'.

- OUTLINER_MT_collection
- OUTLINER_MT_collection_new (required when sorting from master scene collection)

Sorting ascending or descending.

Sorting direct children or recursive from active layer collection.

### Limitation Outliner display mode must be set to 'VIEW_LAYER'.

[image: ![alt text](image.png)]

## General Operation

Right click on a collection in the outliner (this will be considered the parent collection for operations).

[image: ![alt text](image-1.png)]

At the bottom of the context popup menu you will see an option for "Sort Collections" which expands to available options.

## Script

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "VL_Sort",
    "author": "Nezumi",
    "version": (0, 0, 2),
    "blender": (4, 0, 2),
    "location": "Outliner > rightclick menu > Sort Collections",
    "description": "Sort layer collections in outliner",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Interface",
}

import bpy


class USER_OT_sort_colls(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'user.sort_colls'
    bl_label = "Sort Collections"

    reverse: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
    recursive_children: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        area = [a for a in context.screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER'][0]
        cond = area.spaces[0].display_mode == 'VIEW_LAYER'
        return cond

    def execute(self, context):
        m_vcoll = context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection
        start_coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection

        def sort_child_colls(p_vcoll, rev = False):
            c_vcolls = p_vcoll.children
            s_vcolls = sorted(c_vcolls.keys(), reverse = rev)
            for vcoll in c_vcolls:
                c_vcolls.unlink(vcoll)
            for k in s_vcolls:
                c_vcolls.link(bpy.data.collections.get(k))

        def sort_child_rec(p_vcoll = m_vcoll, rev = False):
            c_vcolls = p_vcoll.children_recursive
            for coll in list(c_vcolls):
                if len(coll.children) == 0:
                    c_vcolls.remove(coll)
            for coll in c_vcolls:
                sort_child_colls(coll, rev)
            sort_child_colls(p_vcoll, rev)
        
        if not self.recursive_children:
            sort_child_colls(start_coll, self.reverse)
        else:
            sort_child_rec(start_coll, self.reverse)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class USER_MT_vlsort_sub1(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = 'Children Only'
    bl_idname = 'USER_MT_vlsort_sub1'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sort_c_asc = layout.operator("user.sort_colls", text="Sort Ascending", icon='SORT_ASC')
        sort_c_asc.reverse = False
        sort_c_asc.recursive_children = False
        sort_c_desc = layout.operator("user.sort_colls", text="Sort Descending", icon='SORT_DESC')
        sort_c_desc.reverse = True
        sort_c_desc.recursive_children = False


class USER_MT_vlsort_sub2(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = 'Children Recursive'
    bl_idname = 'USER_MT_vlsort_sub2'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sort_r_asc = layout.operator("user.sort_colls", text="Sort Ascending", icon='SORT_ASC')
        sort_r_asc.reverse = False
        sort_r_asc.recursive_children = True
        sort_r_desc = layout.operator("user.sort_colls", text="Sort Descending", icon='SORT_DESC')
        sort_r_desc.reverse = True
        sort_r_desc.recursive_children = True


class USER_MT_vlsort_main(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = 'Sort Collections'
    bl_idname = 'USER_MT_vlsort_main'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.menu(USER_MT_vlsort_sub1.bl_idname)
        layout.menu(USER_MT_vlsort_sub2.bl_idname)


def menu_item_draw_func_sort(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu("USER_MT_vlsort_main")


classes = [
    USER_OT_sort_colls,
    USER_MT_vlsort_sub1,
    USER_MT_vlsort_sub2,
    USER_MT_vlsort_main,
    ]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_collection.append(menu_item_draw_func_sort)
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_collection_new.append(menu_item_draw_func_sort)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    register()
```

## Original Answer

Below is an ugly script but should be functional in blender 3.x and 4.x.
Note this only affects the 1st hierarchy level not recursive levels.

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context

vcols = C.view_layer.layer_collection.collection.children
s_vcols = sorted(vcols.keys())

for vcol in vcols:
    vcols.unlink(vcol)

for k in s_vcols:
    vcols.link(bpy.data.collections.get(k))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Hopefully one day the developer can include an option for this in the outliner.